# When does Emacs enter command loop?

Tags: commands, eval, read

I'm reading [`(info "(elisp) Command Overview")`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Overview.html#index-post_002dcommand_002dhook):

> Variable: `post-command-hook` 
> : ... ... 
> : This hook is also run **when Emacs first enters the command loop** (at which point `this-command` and `last-command` are both `nil`).

Users may need to know the exact time point referred to here to determine how to utilize this feature.
But after searching in `(info "(elisp) Startup Summary")`, no relevant information was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence to entering the command loop for the first time is:

```
main()                  /* defined in src/emacs.c */
Frecursive_edit()       /* defined in src/keyboard.c */
recursive_edit_1()      /* ditto */
command_loop()          /* ditto */
```

Comment: The manual ([Summary: Sequence of Actions at Startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html)) currently says that Emacs starts mainly through 31 steps. I just want to figure out at which step the time mentioned in the question falls, or between which two steps.

Comment: Calling `normal-top-level` (and hence all of those listed steps) is (essentially) the very first thing that `command_loop` does.

Comment: I suspect the call to `post-command-hook` in question will be the one near the top of `command_loop_1`.  There are things about that code which I do not understand, though, so I can't say much more about it.

Comment: It seems that whether to mention "*`post-command-hook` is also run when Emacs first enters the command loop*" in the manual is not important, because its value cannot be changed at the beginning of startup unless you modify Emacs C source code.

Comment: Perhaps the note is for users who are dumping their own Emacs executable.  That might be a way to give it an initial non-nil value before the command loop is entered.